# Why is fc -l 1 (aka history 1) in zsh script limited to only 30 commands?

Tags: zsh

When I run a `fc -l 1` from the shell I get back the full history from .zsh_history. When I run the same command from a script its only being limited to the last 30. Any ideas why?

I have the following zsh history settings from oh-my-zsh

```
if [ -z $HISTFILE ]; then
   HISTFILE=$HOME/.zsh_history
fi

HISTSIZE=10000
SAVEHIST=10000

setopt appendhistory
setopt extended_history
setopt hist_expire_dups_first
setopt hist_ignore_dups # ignore duplication command history list
setopt hist_ignore_space
setopt hist_verify
setopt inc_append_history
setopt share_history
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put an `echo $HISTSIZE` into your script it's probably 30. Scripts do not source the `.zshrc`, so your history settings are not known to the script.

Put the history specific options into its own file `history.zsh` and source it from the script AND use `fc -R` to read the history file before any other call to `fc`:

```
source ${ZDOTDIR-$HOME}/.zsh/history.zsh
fc -R
...
fc -l 1
```